# How to fetch info from a table and create a new table row on every third record

Tags: php, html

I have a table and I want it to display three columns and on the 4th, 7th, 10th etc etc I want it to create a new table row. If I have 6 entries then it will be two rows and I had 7 entries it will create 3 rows.

I am able to do pull the info from a SQL table but I am trying to learn how I can make it do the above effect.

The table being created I would like to create a new table row on every +3

```
<style type="text/css">
table {
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
width: 33%; 
}
</style>

<table>
<?php
include "db.php";

// ***Count Rows ***
$connection_count = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$count = "SELECT * from equipment";
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection_count, $count)) {
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
//print $rowcount;

// *** Fetch all Records ***
$connection_fetch = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($connection_fetch->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection_fetch->connect_error);
}

$select = "SELECT * FROM equipment";
$resultselect = $connection_fetch->query($select);

while ($row = $resultselect->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "\n<td>";
    echo $row["Equipment_Name"];
    echo "</td>";
}

$connection_fetch->close();
$connection_count->close();
?>
</table>
```

Comment: NB you appear to be making two identical database connections and executing the same query twice - you could optimise that...

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a counter for the row number, and use a modulo expression to determine whether or not to output a `<tr>` tag:

```php
$rowNum = 0;
echo "\n<tr>";
while ($row = $resultselect->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "\n<td>";
    echo $row["Equipment_Name"];
    echo "</td>";
    if (!(++$rowNum % 3) && ($rowNum < $rowcount)) {
       echo "\n</tr>";
       echo "\n<tr>";
    }
}
echo "\n</tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks Rob It kinda works the way I want it but I get this message Undefined variable: rowCount

Comment: @ChrisReilly :  remove `&& ($rowNum < $rowCount)` and see what happens

Comment: My mistake - I was referring to `$rowcount` that was set by your earlier code but got the capitalisation wrong.  Answer updated.